# How may I export the output of SQL query in Excel fetched through PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using this power-shell script to fetch the versions of all SQL Servers in a list.

How may I export the result columns (only query output not error messages) into excel and send to email after the script is run?

Can someone help me add the required script please?

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
$ServerInstences = Get-Content "D:\DBA\All_Server_monitoring\ServerList.txt"
$SQLQuery = @"
Select @@Servername 'Server Name' ,@@version 'Version'
"@
 $DBName = "master"
 $ServerInstences |

ForEach-Object {
    $ServerObject = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $_
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $_ -Database $DBName -Query $SQLQuery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to export data to a csv file is by using `Export-CSV` which takes an input object (or object array) and a path and can fill out the csv file from that object/array. For you, it would look like this:

```
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $_ -Database $DBName -Query $SQLQuery
New-Item -Path "MYPATH.csv"
Export-CSV -Path "MYPATH.csv" -InputObject $results -Append
```

CSV files are versatile and can be opened with the most lightweight text editors. They also can be easily emailed and opened with Excel.